# Querying a record with EF returns a null GUID primary key while it's not

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to query a single record and update a value but I get the `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` when I call the `SaveChanges()` method.

From what I understand. The exception is called because the record returned by the query has a null primary key but in the database, the record does have an ID.

For your information I use a `Guid` as the primary key, which is generated on Add

I used the code-first approach to creating my SQL Server database.

Any ideas what could cause this?

**Update:** after further debugging it's seems my Invoice object is created by using the wrong constructor (I implemented it for something else) adding a public `Invoice()`; seems to stop it to go through the other constructor but the `Id` value is this empty (other fields are set properly)

Here's is a simplified version of my implementation:

*`Invoice` class*

```
public class Invoice
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    
    public string InvoiceNumber { get; set; }

    ...

    public Invoice (Guid owner, Guid id, string fileName, long fileSize)
    {
        Owner = owner;
        FileId = id;
        FileName = fileName;
        FileSize = fileSize;
    }
}
```

*`OnModelCreating`*

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Invoice>(entity =>
    {
        entity.Property(e => e.Id)
            .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

        entity.Property(e => e.InvoiceNumber);
    });

    OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
}
```

*Record update*

```
using (var db = new TheCompanyDbContext())
{
    Invoice invoice = db.Invoices.Where(x => x.ShouldBeExtracted == true).FirstOrDefault();

    if (invoice != null)
    {
        invoice.InvoiceNumber = "does this work";
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

My `Id` column definition in the database:

[image: id column definition]

The record I'm trying to update:

[image: record to update]

Value retrieved by the query:

[image: query values]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it seems the constructor i had for the class invoice was causing issues.
I created a default one and it seems to solve the issue

```
public Invoice() { }
```

Comment: Indeed; looks like EF used your constructor but your constructor never actually set the Id so it remained default. By providing an empty constructor, EF can use a pattern like `new Invoice(){ Id = ...` instead